# Muti_Image_Pickerで選択したPhotoに"Selected"のマークをつけたい

Tags: flutter

FlutterでMulti_Image_Pickerを使用し2枚のPhotoを選択し、その後別の写真を選択するために再度Photo Libraryを開けた時に、前に選択したPhotoがわかるように"Selected"マークをつけたいです。どのようなコードが必要でしょうか。
ご教示の方、よろしくお願いいたします。

私のコードは以下の通りです。

```
resultList = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(
    maxImages: 2,
    selectedAssets: images,
    enableCamera: true,
    cupertinoOptions: CupertinoOptions(
      selectionFillColor: "#ff11ab",
      selectionTextColor: "#ffffff",
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Multi_Image_Pickerのバージョン教えてもらえませんか、今公式のページからみるとMulti_Image_Pickerはもうサポートしていません。
その公式ページに以下のパッケージが勧められました：
https://pub.dev/packages/wechat_assets_picker/versions/1.5.0/example

ご質問している機能の実現はむずかしいくないと思います
具体的なコードは出さないですが、考え方だけ

1. shared_preferencesのパッケージを使ってデバイス上に情報を保存する.（例えば写真のファイル名やIDなど）
2. ページを閉じる時に情報をデバイス上に保存
3. 再度ページを開く時にデバイスから情報を読み込んで写真を選択するようにする

以上

Comment: multi_image_pickerの4.7.15を使用しています。以下multi_image_picker2の5.0.2を使用しても同じでした。https://pub.dev/packages/multi_image_picker2 ご指摘されているwechat_assets_pickerとデバイス情報取得でやります。ありがとうございました。